# How do I get Ubuntu out of the way of Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I installed Ubuntu on my desktop and put it on a completely separate hard drive from Windows 10, but it still seems to have hijacked the boot process. No matter which device I try to boot from, this screen always appears (see below picture) and I need to select Windows 10 otherwise it will default to Ubuntu. When it did this is messed up my Windows 10 and I used a recovery point I happened to make earlier that day and it started running again.

[image]

Sorry for what is likely a duplicate post, I don't even really know how to Google it and try to find the answer. Please link me to a relevant post and delete this one if necessary.

Comment: I fail to understand your question exactly. Do you want to boot only from Windows 10 or only from Ubuntu? Please edit the title.

Comment: Yes. Normally it boots up and lets me select whether to go into Mobo BIOS, or select a boot device. If I didn't explicitly select the drive with Ubuntu it would just boot up to Win like normal. Now, no matter what I do it goes to that screen

Comment: You can configure Grub to make the default the last boot option or you can configure it to always make Windows 10 the default boot option. Both of these are handy when Windows reboots whilst installing updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change which OS grub boots by default.
In terminal, do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that says:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

and change 0 to the grub menu item that you would like to boot first by default. In your case, it should be entry 4. To double check, or if you forget the boot order, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg

After you made the changes, save it, and then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quickest way to read the boot entries seems to be this: `grep -E '^menuentry' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

When installing I think the easiest way to avoid this problem is to disconnect (unplug) the internal drive from your computer. Then the installer cannot auto-select the internal drive, which is otherwise a problem in UEFI mode.

This was discussed also in this link:

[How to create a standalone bootable Ubuntu USB disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859208/how-to-create-a-standalone-bootable-ubuntu-usb-disk/859274)

Now that you have this system, the best option is probably to configure grub as suggested by WinEunuuchs2Unix and Roger G. The following link might help you,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup)

Windows is the menu entry #5 in your screenshot so I think you should use

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=4
```

in the file **/etc/default/grub** and run the command

```
sudo update-grub
```